How to add a pointing arrow to my widget?
I use borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16), to make borders circular, but is there a builtin way to add it a pointy end ?
More explanation:
I have this dart code,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            ),
            child: Text(
              'uz 01 BB 222 B',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            ),
            child: Text(
              'uz 01 CC 333 C',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            ),
            child: Text(
              '+ Login account',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),

Which looks like this

But I want it to have a pointy end, similar to this picture,


You could use the css property clip-path.
Easiest way would be to put another div with a set height above your div here. And then clip-path the shape of the triangle at the end. I'd suggest using the polygon function with it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path
